# Google Calendar: limit API access to a single calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'd like for my app to add/delete/update events on a user's Google Calendar. The app only needs to delete and update events that the app itself has added.

Have I understood it correctly, that in order for this to work, the users have to give the app full access to their Google Calendars, meaning that the app could potentially read and delete private events on any calendar?

Or, is there a way to limit the access that a user gives to the app, for example, allowing the app to create a single calendar and only giving it access to events on that one calendar?

I've read through the relevant Google Calendar API, and I'm not seeing that this is possible. However, giving full access seems crazy and unnecessary!

Comment: If you have read the items 3 and 4 from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#OAuth2Authorizing), it was mentioned there that "When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access." this scope was declared in the same documentation. So I think those scope will help you achieved what do you want to do in your app.

Comment: According to the scope documentation, it looks like there is a general calendar scope access, but not a scope that only gives access to a particular calendar or that only gives update/delete access to events added by the app. That's what seems insane! I'm not going to ask anyone to give me full access to everything in all their calendars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this isn't possible. Google, why!?

What I ended up doing was skipping the API and using a calendar subscription. Limited use since the user needs to be able to set up a subscription and, especially, because Google takes up to a day to update subscribed calendars.